# Angular bootstrap ngb timepicker convert custom time into timepicker readable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-bootstrap

I have an application where I get the time in this format "hh:mm:ss" from the API response and I want to show the time in the timepicker,

What I have tried is taking the substring from the time and converting them into integer and sending them as JSON like this

```
timeFromApi = "19:00:00"

const model = {
hour: parseInt(timeFromApi.substring(0,2)),
minute: parseInt(timeFromApi.substring(3,5))
}

<ngb-timepicker [(ngModel)]="model "></ngb-timepicker>
```

can there be another better way to do this? I don't like the substring method, because it's not sure that every time the data will be valid

Comment: check my solution below.

Comment: you can use a custom adapter as show in the docs: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/timepicker/examples#adapter. See that an adapter is only a class that extends from `NgbTimeAdapter` and has two functions: `fromModel` and `toModel`

Answer (score 0):

```
timeFromApi = "19:00:00"
const timesArray = timeFromApi.split(":").map((time) => +time);
const model = {
hour: timesArray[0],
minute: timesArray[1]
}
```

Comment: is there any other way to parse the time and convert it into javascript time and using the ngbTimeStruct we can fill the timepicker ?